# Grails 2.1.0 Plugin transitive dependencies

Tags: grails, dependencies, grails-plugin

I have written a custom plugin which depends on Spring-Social Core and Spring-Security Core.  I can see below definition in dependencies.groovy in packaged zip file.

```
MYCustomPluginBuildConfig: 
 plugins { 
        build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion") 
        compile(":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3") 
        compile(":spring-social-core:0.1.31") { 
            transitive = false 
        } 
        //checkstyle for groovy 
        test(':codenarc:0.18') 
    }
```

When I include this plugin at runtime scope in my project and run 'grails compile' it cannot find Spring Social classes.

```
.grails/projects/myproject/plugins/web-application-common-paypal-access-1.0.39/src/groovy/com/mycompany/SignInAdapter.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class grails.plugins.springsocial.signin.SpringSocialSimpleSignInAdapter 
 @ line 3, column 1. 
   import grails.plugins.springsocial.signin.SpringSocialSimpleSignInAdapter
```

I am not able to figure out why.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Abhijith

Comment: I am actually having a similar problem, and I am (as @DerekSilfe suggests) specifying my custom plugins as compile-time dependencies. For the repositories{} closure in BuildConfig.groovy, I'm using the flatDir approach.  
`flatDir name:'customplugin', dirs:'/path/to/custom/plugin'`  

While it _does_ install the plugin, it doesn't transitively resolve the dependencies contained in dependencies.groovy (or BuildConfig.groovy before I package the plugin). Thus, when it tries to compile the plugin's source files, it fails to import some needed classes.

Comment: Additionally, if I look in the dependency-report, while my custom plugin is listed there, it is listed as having no dependencies. My guess is that local plugins simply don't get transitive resolution, probably because they were intended to work offline.

Answer (score 0):

If your grails application has code which references classes within your plugin, or classes which the plugin includes due to transitive dependencies, you should include that plugin as a `compile` time dependency instead of a `runtime` dependency.

Based on the error message, `SignInAdapter` is referencing `SpringSocialSimpleSignInAdapter`. Try updating your `BuildConfig.groovy` as follows:

```
compile ':my-social-security-plugin:0.1'
```